# PHP iOS Push notifications arabic multilingual text larger in size

Tags: php, text, apple-push-notifications, arabic

I don't really know how to ask these but hopefully i can make myself clear enough for you to understand my questions

Below is the Arabic text which I want to send via `Apple iPhone Push Notifications`:

يبدا بقرص العقيلي واللقيمات وينتهي مع خالد حرية بالامارات نكهة وبهار مع القصار-٦ مساءا على يشان الليله في انا والعسل مع غاده عبدالرازق تلفزيون الكويت

Can i send this long text?

Because when I prepare a payload, it says `360 bytes` of size. While Apple allows only `256 bytes` of payload.

What can be done for same?

I'm using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14563097/sending-multiple-iphone-push-notifications-apns-php-tutorial) for same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got one `trick` [not sure this is permanent soln though] temporarily: May be handy to other people in future

commented below code of line

```
//$payload = json_encode($body);
```

And directly appending `JSON format` to `Payload variable`

```
$payload = '{"aps":{"alert":"'.$message.'","sound":"default","badge":"+1"}}';
```

Here, `$message` will be my `Arabic string` for actula message and `it WORKS` !!

Comment: when change my code as above i got 'array' message on iphone.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't sound like this is something you can work around. Try shortening the notification message and then pointing the user towards your app where you can display a more descriptive message.